# Highcharts error when loading data table throw export module

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to represent data and want to use the export-data module to show/hide data table below chart.

Apparently, I'm using all the required scripts in the correct order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

After these calls, I code the chart in an usual way, using just basic options: title, axis, series...

Everything works fine at loading the chart, but when I click on "View data table", the table actually is shown, but the js console shows an error:

```
export-data.src.js:488 Uncaught TypeError: b.closest is not a function
    at export-data.src.js:488:33
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at f.<anonymous> (export-data.src.js:487:17)
    at highcharts.src.js:1654:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at x (highcharts.src.js:1651:17)
    at f.d.toggleDataTable (export-data.src.js:1208:21)
    at f.onclick (export-data.src.js:1252:25)
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (exporting.src.js:2065:45)
```

Line No. 488 at export-data-src.js is this:
[Code lines from Highcharts export-data-src.js module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFWg.png)

After this error happens, I can't hide the data-table or update it through js functions.

Comment: Hi @Javi Delgado, I've tried to reproduce the issue, but everything seems to work in this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bqu3st7w/ Could you adapt the demo to show the problem?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I've just updated the fiddle and now it shows the problem. I've been doing try and error research, and I've found that the error is produced by the tag <thead> of a previous table, as shown at the fiddle. Any ideas about why is this happening? http://jsfiddle.net/eujv2tnp/

Comment: Thanks for the example. The problem is a Highcharts regression bug - it works fine with Highcharts v9: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yox4bku2/ As a workaround you can overwrite the `afterViewData` event: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e9a3o0xL/ Could you report the problem on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Feel free to post it as an answer, so I can vote it.